# Question on vectors regarding plane moving around earth?

Tags: vectors

A plane is revolving around the earth with a speed 100 km/hr at a constant height from the surface of earth. The change in the velocity as it travels half circle is

Answer is 200km/hr

First things I noticed :
There is no acceleration of the plane given.There is no constant force as well given.Then why is change in velocity simply not 0.

2 Drew a vector 100 j upwards and 100(-j) downwards. When two vectors are opposite they cut each other.Why don’t they do it here ? =0

[image]
Please help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the difference  in the two vectors, $v_0 = 100\hat{j}$ and $v_1 = -100\hat{j}$ so $$v_0 + v_1 = 0$$ but the magnitude of the change in velocity is $$|v_0 - v_1| = |200 \hat{j}| = 200(km/hr)$$An massive object which moves in a circle must be accelerating, in fact the magnitude of it's acceleration must be $a = \frac{v^2}{r}$ where $v$ is the linear velocity and $r$ is the distance from the center of the circle.

Comment: It should be v1 - v0 right since change in velocity is vf-vi.

Comment: Please do check

Comment: Part 2 of my question that I wrote. Is that true ?

Comment: For part 2, you say they "cut each other," what does this mean?

Comment: It means that let’s say if you are moving at speed 100m/s north and then 100m/s south.These two vectors will cut each other.Simply means their displacement is 0.

Comment: Resultant is 0.

Comment: yes, $v_1 + v_0$ = 0. as for the other part, I could have stated $v_0 = -100\hat{j}$ and $v_1 = 100\hat{j}$ since a reference frame was not given, presumably the change in velocity is meant to be a positive value, regardless of orientation, in fact a scalar not a vector. will add this to my post.

Comment: I hope I am correct with the analogy that I used for part 2 ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not very good at drawing pictures in MathJax, however as stated, the sum of the vectors is $0$ but the magnitude of their difference is $200$, could you clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: Refer my drawing above now

Comment: Please check out [this link](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors) or some other reference which talks about adding and subtracting two vectors.

Comment: Ok sure.Thank you.

Comment: Hope it helps, essentially adding the two vectors gives the zero vector but subtracting them gives a vector of magnitude 200. @srijannahar